# What will happen if we declare a char variable with starting '&' in C++?

Tags: c++, variables, character

I want to know a brief difference in character variable names such as starting with '&' and starting with a letter as follows:

```
char &c = 'a'; char a = 'a';
```

What is the brief difference between variable &c and a.

Comment: Ampersand is not part of the name, it's part of the type. You have a variable named `a` of type `char`, and a variable named `c` of type `char&`, aka "reference to `char`". Read about references in your favorite C++ textbook.

Comment: you need to check the basic concepts about references, pointers etc

Comment: `char a = 'a';` is a variable declaration that initializes the variable `a` with the single character `'a'`. However, `char &c = 'a';` is not valid C++. It's almost a reference declaration, but right-hand-side needs to be a variable, or something that can the reference can alias/bind to.

Answer (score 1):

I can guarantee that your compiler will reject `char &c = 'a';`.
In C++, rather than defining a pointer (`char *c = &a`), you can also define a **reference** to an **existing** variable or function. A reference is defined by adding an ampersand before the reference name. Diffrentiating from pointers, a reference must refer to a given variable. Also, once a reference is defined, it cannot be changed. See the following examples.

```
// I'll use char in the examples
char a = 'a', aa = 'z';
char *b1 = &a;  // OK, defines pointer b1 pointing to a
char *b2;       // OK, defines pointer b2 but not assigning an address
char &c1 = a;   // OK, c1 is a reference to a
char &c2;       // Wrong. A reference must have a referee
char &c3 = 'c'; // Wrong. Referee must be LHS
int x = 0;
char& c3 = x;   // Wrong. c3 and x type must match

// b1 is of type "char*", c1 is of type "char&", effectively the same as "char"
a = 'd'; cout << *b1 << c1; // Output: dd
*b1 = 'e'; cout << a << c1; // Output: ee
cout << sizeof(a) << " " << sizeof(b1) << " " << sizeof(c1);
                            // Output: 1 4 1 (or "1 8 1" on a 64-bit system)
b1 = &aa; cout << *b1;      // Output: z
&c1 = aa;                   // Wrong. Can't reassign references
c1 = aa; cout << c1;        // Output: z (Seems OK)
cout << a;                  // Output: z (Oops, original a is also changed)
```